# AWS Cognito ListUsersRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to make a request to Cognito to get a list of users, whose name/email/given_name.. start with some strings.

Could we make ListUsersRequest with different filters?

I tried this, but it does not seem to work:

```
String filter = "username ^= \"" + searchKey + "\" or name ^= \"" + searchKey + "\" or email ^= \"" + searchKey + "\"" ;
ListUsersRequest request = ListUsersRequest.builder()
                    .filter(filter)    
                    .userPoolId(COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature with Cognito yet. Either you have to call Filter couple times or you need to sync Cognito data to your database and perform SQL on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add multiple conditions to the ListUsersRequest filter parameter it's not supported by Cognito,

> AttributeName: The name of the attribute to search for. You can only search for one attribute at a time.

Refer[Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html#CognitoUserPools-ListUsers-request-Filter) for more details

```
ListUsersRequest listUsersRequest = ListUsersRequest.builder()
                .userPoolId(userPoolId)
                .filter(String.format("given_name ^= \"%1$s\" ", userName))
                .build();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).